# c++ difference between a function returning a new object vs assigning the function's result to the object that called it

Tags: c++

The question is kind of awkward, but hopefully my example makes more sense.

As reference, the program I'm writing has a window for a user to enter information in, and when the user clicks save the window creates a Person object, fills it in with the info from the window with populatePerson(), and calls a function in the Person class to save out the information to a file.

I struggled for a bit to find a way for the window class to call the Person function, because I would get an error about not being able to call a non-static function, but then realized that I needed a second "empty" Person object to call the savePerson() function. I also made a similar setup for loading a Person from file.

ex:

```
void Person::savePerson(Person p)
{
    //open file
    //write p to file
    //return
}

Person Person::loadFile(String filename)
{
    //open file
    //make new person
    //put file contents into person
    //return person
}
```

in order to call these i needed to do something like this

```
Person NewPerson = populatePerson();

Person Save;
Save.savePerson(NewPerson);    

Person Load;
NewPerson = Load.loadPerson("file the person was saved to");
```

I thought this was a bit awkward because I'm not using the Save and Load Persons for anything other than just calling functions in their class. The object I care about is NewPerson.

Then I found that I could use *this to do the operations in savePerson() and loadPerson() instead of passing in a Person or returning a Person.

ex:

```
void Person::savePerson()
{
    //open file
    //write *this to file

}

void Person::loadPerson(String filename)
{
    //open file
    //read file and put it in *this

}
```

and then call them like this

```
Person NewPerson = populatePerson();

NewPerson.savePerson();
NewPerson.loadPerson("file the person was saved to");
```

The second solution seems to make more sense to me, and both of these ways seem to compile and run just fine. The question is basically, is one of these solutions better than the other one? Is either one something that's bad to do? Would either way tend to cause unexpected problems?

Also, would it be better to instead make the save and load functions static in the first place so the window can call them without needing an instance of Person to call them?

(Sorry for the psuedocode, the actual code is mostly Qt which might cause confusion, but this seemed like more of a general C++ question.)

Comment: The 2nd solution is better than the first because it avoids creating all those unnecessary objects.  Have you thought about making the file name a parameter when saving?  Yes, it would be reasonable to make load/save static; they'd be better still as a separate class (e.g. `PersonFile`) because you could leverage a constructor/destructor pair to open and close the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trust your intuitions; the second is the better of the two.  Having to create 3 Persons instead of one, when you are only interested in one Person, is a dead giveaway.  savePerson clearly makes perfect sense as written ("save me") and loadPerson runs a close second ("populate me from a file"), although if you made a constructor for Person that took the file to load from, you can avoid having to either have Person be uninitialized until loadPerson is called, or wasting time initializing it just to overwrite it using loadPerson.

Comment: Thanks for the insight, guys. I haven't quite nailed which part of the program will be responsible for providing the filenames for saving and loading, but your suggestions sound good.